# Getting at net.sf.saxon.dotnet.DotNetPullProvider.next() Error in C# with Saxon

Tags: c#, saxon

I am Using Saxon-9EE for XSLT2.0 transformation in C#(Visual studio 2012). but some times getting below error while loading source document(xml size have 25MB). i tried same code for other documents(less than 10 MB) it's working well. can you please help me how to resolve it. thanks

```
Method >>    End Copy Directory >>   3/28/2013 3:22:36 AM:857
 >>         at net.sf.saxon.dotnet.DotNetPullProvider.next()
   at net.sf.saxon.pull.PullFilter.next()
   at net.sf.saxon.pull.PullPushTee.next()
   at net.sf.saxon.pull.PullConsumer.consume()
   at net.sf.saxon.pull.PullPushCopier.copy()
   at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendPullSource(PullSource , Receiver , ParseOptions )
   at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Source source, Receiver receiver, ParseOptions options)
   at net.sf.saxon.Configuration.buildDocument(Source source, ParseOptions parse
Options)
   at net.sf.saxon.Configuration.buildDocument(Source source)
   **at Saxon.Api.DocumentBuilder.Build(XmlReader reader)**
   at DocxCreator_XSL.DocxCreator.CreateDocx() in c:\Users\velagasx\Documents\Vi
sual Studio 2012\Projects\SampleProjects\DocxCreator_XSL\DocxCreator.cs:line 99
>>       3/28/2013 3:22:42 AM:745
```

Comment: That looks like an exception stack trace, what is the message and type of the exception?

Comment: PS: it sometimes takes us a few days to spot a Saxon-specific enquiry on this list. If you report it directly at saxonica.plan.io you'll get a quicker response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple and obvious explanation is that (a) your XML isn't well-formed (or valid), and (b) the error handling in your application is inadequate. The routine at the top of your stack trace is calling the Microsoft XML parser asking for the next event, and testing for exceptions coming from the XML parser. If it gets an exception, this should emerge at the level of Saxon.Api.DocumentBuilder.Build() in the form of a Saxon.Api.Exception; there should be some basic information here about the nature of the error, which for some reason you haven't shown us.

It's possible you would get better diagnostics if you build the document using the Apache Xerces parser (which is built in to Saxon on .NET) rather than the Microsoft parser. This would also have the benefit that the XPath id() and idref() functions work properly - they don't in the case of documents built using the Microsoft parser, because the M$ parser doesn't supply enough information to the application about the DTD.